# redis sorted set implementation

Tags: redis, architecture

In redis documentation is said that: "Sorted sets are implemented via a dual-ported data structure containing both a skip list and a hash table, so every time we add an element Redis performs an O(log(N)) operation".
How can I prove it can be calculated in order of log(n)?

Comment: No need to prove it yourself - skiplists exhibit that complexity as documented all over, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list